# Confused why my regex expression isn't working?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Attempting to create a regex expression that splits a string at ',' and '\n' and then a passed in custom delimiter (which is signified by firstChar in my code).

Format for the string being passed in: {delimiter}\n{numbers}. I've used regex101 online and it seems to work on there but in my actual code it doesn't split at the custom delimiter so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
if (str.includes('\n')) {
    let firstChar = str.slice(0, 1);
    if (parseInt(firstChar)) {
      strArr = str.split(/,|\n/) ;
    } else {
      strArr = str.split(/[,|\n|firstChar]/);
    }
}
```

expect ';\n2;5' to equal 7 but my array splits into [";", "2;5"] for some reason.

Comment: Your first character isn't a number so you end up going to else statement every time

Comment: @CodeManiac that's what I want. If the first character is a number I want to split it just at '\n' and ','. Otherwise, I want to split it at the previously mentioned delimiters as well as the custom delimiter passed in (';' in this example).

Comment: `[,|\n|firstChar]` is exactly the same as `[\n,|Cafhirst]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first character isn't a number so you go to else condition directly, if you want a dynamic regex then you need to build it using `RegExp`

Also you don't need character class here

```
/[,|\n|firstChar]/
```

it should be

```
/,|\n|firstChar/
```

---

```js
let splitter = (str) => {
  if (str.includes('\n')) {
    let firstChar = str.slice(0, 1);
    if (parseInt(firstChar)) {
      return str.split(/,|\n/);
    } else {
      let regex = new RegExp(`,|\\n|\\${firstChar}`, 'g') // building a dynamic regex here
      return str.split(regex).filter(Boolean)
    }
  }

}

console.log(splitter(";\n2;5"))
console.log(splitter("*\n2*5"))
```

Comment: when I run your code it splits like so: [
  ";",
  "2;5"
]
which is not what I want. I want [2,5]

Comment: @JoeSpinelli You need to build a dynamic regex, check the update one,

Comment: I've never worked with dynamic regex before. What about my case makes me need it? Why doesn't passed it in like so: str.split(/,|\n|firstChar/) work? firstChar === ';' so isn't it the same as simply passing ';' into the expression?

Comment: @JoeSpinelli `firstChar` will literally be treated as word `firstChar` not the variable `firstChar`, when ever you want to build a dynamic regex you need to build using `RegExp`

Comment: wowww I can't believe I never realized that smh haha thats so annoying. Thank you so much, you're awesome!

Comment: so now it works for custom delimiters like ';' and '@' but random ones like '$' and '*' it throws an error or splits incorrectly?

Comment: @JoeSpinelli  `$` and `*` are special character in regex and you need to escape them,

Comment: seems as though there's a lot of characters that don't work '(', ')' and '^' are others I found. Is there anyway to allow all characters? I'm not exactly sure what escape them means.

Comment: @JoeSpinelli adding "\\" before character, see the updated one it includes escaping too

Comment: whoa thats so cool!! I appreciate your help so much dang you're a wizard. Sorry last couple questions, what does escaping do and also would you be down to connect on LinkedIn or something?